# Div moves below another div when window resized

Tags: css, html, window-resize

When I resize the browser window my navigation bar div drops below the search box div.
How can I stop the nav bar moving and keep it in the same place? The footer behaves itself and its structured in the same way?

Here's a link...

http://www.signport.co.uk/test/asg_template3.html

Thanks!

Comment: why you are inserting to `.wrapper_menu` `width:100%` when it's resized ? If you will remove `width:100%` it could help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your menu does not have a width specified. Whereas you footer behaves because it has a width specified( div with id `footerleft`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing on Chrome now, removing the width:100% you have set on the navigation bar div (wrapper_menu_full class) seems to do the trick. This 100% refers to its size compared to the containing div (#mainmenu3).

If this still doesn't work on IE7, try setting both divs inside #mainmenu3 to display:inline, although now I'm testing on Chrome it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE YOUR CSS

```
#mainmenu3 {
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

YOU WILL GET THE DESIRE OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

You're using floated elements on both divs (searchfilter and menu). 
When you are using the floated elements, and the width of the last of the floated element exceed parent's width, it goes moves to the next line (belov).

Put this into your css to make it work as you want:

```
#mainmenu3{position:relative;}
#search4{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.wrapper_menu{position:relative;top:0;left:310px;}
```

Comment: Hi, you're tip has made it better - but it still is a bit glitchy. Resizing the window makes the nav bar drop slightly and then when I rollover the links in the navbar the red highlight appears above the link rather than behind it?

Comment: Looks like the line-height 60px is causing the hover issue (megamenu.css line 278).

Comment: don't want to be a nag but there is multiple issues i would fix if it was me in your menu bar. If you would mind, i could rewrite them if you want

Comment: Go for it! It started off as complex dropdown nav bar that I purchased. I've stripped it down so much that now it just a basic looking nav bar but with remnants of the original code.